# Trigger to update converted Lead's Opportunity with information from converted Contact

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, lead-conversion

I'm having an issue with a trigger, and can't seem to figure it out, so I'm hoping someone can help me.

Basically, I wrote a trigger that runs when a lead is converted. It is supposed to populate a field called Contact__c on the new opportunity, with the ID of the Primary Contact of that Opp.

For some reason, it doesn't seem to be putting anything in that field. I added a bunch of debug statements, and it looks like it's having trouble pulling a value from the map

Here's the trigger:

```
trigger AddPrimaryContactToConvertedOpp on Lead (After Update) {


// THIS TRIGGER WILL OVERWRITE ANY CONTACT DEFINED IN THE CUSTOM FIELD CONTACT__C ON THE OPPORTUNITY OBJECT.
// SET THIS FIELD TO READ ONLY OR CHANGE THE FUNCTIONALITY BELOW TO AVIOD DATA BEING OVERWRITTEN BY MISTAKE...


//STEP 1: Create a list of all Opp IDs we are working on, ie: those created in this lead conversion (or batch conversion)
   map <Opportunity,Id> OppsAndContacts = new map <Opportunity,Id>();
   for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
       If (l.IsConverted){
           Opportunity Opp = [SELECT Id from Opportunity where Id = :l.convertedopportunityid];
           OppsAndContacts.put(Opp, l.ConvertedContactID);
           System.Debug('>>> adding to map contact: ' + l.convertedcontactid + ' opp: '+ Opp);
       }
   }
    System.Debug('>>> Printing the map: '+ OppsAndContacts);

//STEP 2: Loop through all records in OppsAndContacts, adding the contactID to the Opps
    if (!OppsAndContacts.isEmpty()){ //only run if there are actually some newly created Opps
       System.Debug('>>> the list of OppsAndContacts is not empty');
       for (Opportunity o : OppsAndContacts.keySet()) {
         o.Contact__c = OppsAndContacts.get(o);
         System.Debug('>>> adding to opp record: ' + o.Id + ' the contact with ID: ' + OppsAndContacts.get(o));
       }

   }//END IF
}//END TRIGGER
```

It seems to be having trouble with `OppsAndContacts.get(o)`

If anyone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: 1) you've got a select statement inside of a for loop on Trigger.new -- not a good idea, you'll break governor limits on batch operations; 2) normal practice would be for your map to be <ID,ID> that is, oppoId to ContactId; 3) your trigger doesn't actually do any dml to update the Oppos

Comment: Thanks for answering! I can switch the map to be Id,Id... . The line that I thought would update the Opp record is "o.Contact__c = OppsAndContacts.get(o);". What do you think I should change it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trigger AddPrimaryContactToConvertedOpp on Lead (After Update) {


// THIS TRIGGER WILL OVERWRITE ANY CONTACT DEFINED IN THE CUSTOM FIELD CONTACT__C ON THE OPPORTUNITY OBJECT.
// SET THIS FIELD TO READ ONLY OR CHANGE THE FUNCTIONALITY BELOW TO AVIOD DATA BEING OVERWRITTEN BY MISTAKE...

// [1] Build list of Oppos to update
List<Opportunity> oUpdList = new List<Opportunity> ();
for (Lead l : Trigger.new) 
    if (l.IsConverted && l.convertedOpportunityId != null)
        oUpdList.add(new Opportunity(id = l.convertedOpportunityId, contact__c = l.convertedContactId));

// [2] Update the converted Oppos
update oUpdList;  // could be Database.update(oUpdList,false) if you want partial successes
}
```

Comment: Okay so I'm trying to understand your code. Looks like it's making a list of Opportunities to update, and then updating them? Cool!    Well, for some reason it's giving me an error on line 17 - expecting a right parentheses, found ';'. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Just added a right parenthesis to the end of the line, and...... IT WORKED!!!! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: sorry about the missing paren; fixed.  In order for an after trigger to do any DML, it needs to have a list of the sobject to update/insert/delete; only before insert/update triggers implicitly insert/update  the trigger.new sobject

Comment: I get it! That explains why the code I copied from a before insert trigger on Opp wasn't working here.

Comment: i woke up at 0300h and realized the trigger could be simpler -- updated answer